# htaccess 301 redirect with query string

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess code that redirects a php file with url parameters to an html file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^test/view\.php$ /test/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

It currently redirects `sampledomain.com/test/view.php?file=1232&text=456`

to `sampledomain.com/test/123&text=456.html`

I would need to redirect keeping only the first parameter value as html file name like this
`sampledomain.com/test/123.html`

Can someone please post the correct htaccess code?

Thanks

Comment: A note: `123&text=465.html`, although a valid file name, is not the most useful in web servers. Try using parameters after the file name: `123.html?text=456`. These can be accessed using PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: 123&text=465.html is the result of the current htaccess code that I need to change

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?file=([^&\ ]+)&text=([&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^test/view\.php$ /test/%1/%2.html? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture only first query parameter instead of using `.*` which captures everything:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)file=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^test/view\.php$ /test/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.